# Converting csv of strings into a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, cell-array

I just started using Octave (No money for Matlab :/) and I'm also new to Stack Overflow, so please pardon any error I make with conventions.

Problem: I have a csv of strings like so:

```
Bob Marley,Kobe Bryant,Michael Jackson,Kevin Hart
```

I would like to make this into a 1 column matrix (I need it in a matrix so that I can combine it with data that are in other matrices).

My approach: I have tried doing `textread`, but this gives me a cell array. I tried converting the resulting cell array to a matrix by using `cell2mat`, but I suspect that I cannot do this because my strings are of varying lengths.

Let me know if any other information is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are in the directory where you have a file "strings.csv" with the content you mentioned in the question, your code whould look like this:

```
fid=fopen('strings.csv');
A=textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter',',');
A=A{1};
A=cellfun(@(x) string(x),A,'uni',0);
B=[A{:}];
```

Comment: I get this error when running your code: `warning: the 'string' function is not yet implemented in Octave`. Maybe this works for Matlab but not for Octave?

Comment: @ShubhamKumar Ok, then I'd like to go back to my original assumption: Does octave even have string matrixes? apparently it has been added to matlab at R2016B and maybe it has not yet been added to Octave. I don't have an installation of Octave so I can't test. This solution works in matlab though.

Comment: You might be right, I just resorted to doing cell arrays. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Yep, `string` objects are Matlab-only. cellstrs (`cell` arrays containing `char` vectors in their cells) is the right way to do it in Octave.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `char` arrays using:

```
fid = fopen('strings.csv');
A = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', ',');
B = char(A{:})
[rows, cols] = size(B)
```

Output is the following:

```
B =
  Bob Marley
  Kobe Bryant
  Michael Jackson
  Kevin Hart

rows =  4

cols =  15
```

As you can see, the number of columns of `B` is the maximum length of all "strings" (Michael Jackson, 15). All other "strings" get whitespaces appended.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but this is pretty neat! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is that simple, you can do it in a one-liner. Use `fileread` to slurp all the data in, and then `strsplit` to separate the elements, and a `'` transpose to convert it to a column vector.

```
x = strsplit(fileread('myfile.txt'), ',')'
```

If you end up with spaces around the commas in your data, upgrade to `regexp`.

```
x = regexp(fileread('myfile.txt'), ' *, *', 'split')
```